# PHP binding error

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to use this script to see if there's a registered using in my database, but I'm having trouble on line 6.  I keep getting the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in
>   -redacted-/check_login.php on line 6

I'm stumped as to why it's failing, because I have a similar statement working on the create user function.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "-redacted-", "-redacted-");

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT user FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
$query->bind_param('ss', $_POST['username'], md5($_POST['password']));
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($result);
$query->fetch();

if($result->num_rows == 1) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
    header("Location: 10.0.0.15/index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: That means `prepare()` got an error and returned `false` instead of a `mysqli_stmt` object. You need to check for errors.

Comment: I expect that your $query is failing - check the return value from the database and see what's happening when it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by referencing a non-existant column/table in your database schema. Hence why the `prepared` is the root cause of this error.

What you should do, is check over your query. Making sure you are:

1. not using `reserved` mysql keywords
2. referencing columns/tables that
   exist within the schema
3. There are no syntax errors within your SQL
   Query

Comment: I presume it was not down to a non-existant reference, it was down to using the reserved word `user`?

Comment: Correct.  It just decided it was going to throw a fit over it.  I switched name and it started working perfectly.

Comment: It's within best practice to avoid using reserved words, but if it's a must. You can escape the words using a back tick.. Example: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ``user``=?` This will tell MySQL that you a referncing a column name and not trying to use a reserved keyword -- Note, only use one backtick each side of the reserved word. There is a formatting problem with SO That I don't know how to overcome.

Comment: Okay, it's not a big deal for me to have it named the way it was.  I'll just keep out of the keywords.

On a slightly different note, Is there an easy way to count how many results are coming back? The above gets rejected as a non-object.

Comment: @Jacobm001 I presume your looking for: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php  which is what springs to mind, to count the current results. If thats not what your asking, then unfortunatly I do not know.